# Stop execution of a Dart program until a key is pressed

Tags: dart

Is there a way to stop the execution of a Dart process until a key is pressed ?

This would be something like :

- In the html file :

```html
<input id="nextstep" type="button" value="nextstep" />
```

- In the dart file :

```dart
void main() { 
  while(true) {
    // Do something here to pause the loop 
    // until the nextstep button is pressed
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add a `keyPress` listener on your `input` to start some extra processing.

```dart
void main() { 
  final input = querySelector("#nextstep");
  input.onKeyPress.listen((e){
    nextProcessingStep();
  });
}
```